# jQuery - Open a URL and select a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

Using GreaseMonkey, looking to select a value and hit the submit button after the page loads. Let's use False/No as an Example

```html
window.addEventListener ("load", LocalMain, false);

function LocalMain () {
  
$('select[name=timeEnabled]').val(1); 
$('input[type=submit]')[0].click(); 


}



  <select name="timeEnabled" onchange="timeUpdated()" class="alignLeft nowrap">
  <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
  <option value="false">No</option></select>

<input name="submit" value="Apply" onclick="return preSubmit()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit">
```

Comment: This makes no sense really. Are you writing this fro a GreaseMonkey script?

Comment: Do you own the site you like to edit and send data? Or you just want to automatic open URL and send form? If so you should consider using plugin called **GreaseMonkey**. You probably will need to use 'GM_getValue' and 'GM_setValue' for variables to execute script including navigating to numerous pages [Grease Monkey wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page)

Comment: No, I was hoping to do this in a Console of Chrome. Open tabs, select the value I want and submit. I own the site that I'm trying to edit. Never heard of GreaseMonkey but I will take a look.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add an example of the HTML that you're trying to run this code on?

Comment: @Twisty I took everyones advice and I think GreaseMonkey is the best bet. I'm trying to make it work but no luck at the moment with the code in the main post. I'm assuming you can't use JS and jQuery together.

Comment: @DavidL.Lee You can use Native JS and JQuery together. In GreaseMonkey, you need to include the JQuery Library. JQuery is simply a framework to make JS easier to use and add functionality. To add this, use: `// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` in your GreaseMonkey Script Header.

Comment: @DavidL.Lee What we need to be able to help better is to see an example of the HTML Code that this GreaseMonkey will be used upon. There may be something else that we don't see cause you have not added it to your post.

Comment: @Twisty ugh, sorry for the formatting. The code isn't coming out that great. I added the select options and the button. The jQuery works if I do it through the Console but not through GreaseMonkey upon Page Load

Comment: We need to see an example of the HTML. Maybe there is not a `input` that is the type to submit. Maybe something else is being used, like `button`. We need to see some of the source of the target.

Comment: I think I got it working...I had to use val("false") intead of (1)

Comment: @DavidL.Lee yeah I saw the suggestion and was going to suggest that it should use `.eq(1)` to select a specific `option`. But that does the job of setting the value to `false` for the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GreaseMonkey, I suspect this is working. Here is a jsFiddle that is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xtmpca4b/

**HTML**

```
<form>
<select name="timeEnabled" onchange="timeUpdated()" class="alignLeft nowrap">
  <option value="true" selected="selected">Yes</option>
  <option value="false">No</option>
</select>

<input name="submit" value="Apply" onclick="return preSubmit()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit">
</form>
```

**GreaseMonkey**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Apply Each Tab
// @date                01/27/2016
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
// @namespace   http://www.your-url-target.com/page-target.html
// @description Select a value from an element and submit the parent form.
// @version     0.1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name='timeEnabled']").val("false");
  $("input[type='submit']")[0].click();
});
```

Make sure to update your `@namespace` to match the target URL. Using the `.ready()` will cause the JQuery to be executed when the page is loaded.

You may also want to consider:

```
$("select[name='timeEnabled']").val("false").parent("form").submit();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xtmpca4b/3/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select a value manually by using `.val(optionIndex)`. Then you can manually click the apply button via `.click()`.

```
$('select[name=timeEnabled]').val(1); // Select the 'No' option for example. 
$('input[type=submit]')[0].click(); // Click the button, use [0] to use the native JS function instead of the jQuery one (which is used for handling onclick events).
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like what you are looking for is a browser plugin that will execute a script on page load. Check out Greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Install that addon in Firefox, write your JavaScript to manipulate the relevant form elements and submit the form (look at their documentation [here](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page)). Then open all your edit links.

Comment: Is this easy to do? This may be difficult for someone who only knows basic programming

Comment: It would be as easy as installing the addon, writing the script to manipulate the DOM in the way you described, then following the Greasemonkey directions for adding a script to their addon. With jQuery, the script might look like `$('#selectElement').val(1);` and then `$('#form').submit();`